# Report designer tool during runtime

Tags: c#, reporting

I need to let the end users to design their owns reports from my applications in c#. There is a way to do it by using infragistics report, telerik or any others?

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help].

Answer (score 1):

The [XtraReports Suite](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/reporting/) allows the end user to customize and create reports.

Here is a [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWHZovQtZVc) on YouTube.